# How to make a one to many and many to many listbox connection in C# asp.net webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

I have the following problem, where I can select an item from one of each of the two Listboxes and put them together into another listbox, however when I select more than 1, it only connects the first one. 
I would like to add the functionality of being able to select more than one on each of the listboxes, and puts all of the selected items together from the first box with each of the ones in the second box, and displays all the combinations in the third one.

I have included my code where the basic functionality that I have is working.
Thanks for any help!

Here's my aspx page

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem>ListItem1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>ListItem2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>ListItem3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            Text="Connect" />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxResult" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my cs page

```
namespace SAM_Phase3
{
    public partial class DoubleListBoxMM : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxResult.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text + ListBox2.SelectedItem.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The output I would hope to get if all items were selected,would be the third textbox with the following items.

```
Item1ListItem1
Item1ListItem2
Item1ListItem3
Item2ListItem1
Item2ListItem2
Item2ListItem3
Item3ListItem1
Item3ListItem2
Item3ListItem3
```

Comment: You need to iterate through each select listbox and added the checked items to your result listbox.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not too sure how to do so with a for loop that takes all the selected items and connects them together, the loop is what i tried, but I couldn't get to work. Thanks

Comment: Show the code for your loop.

Comment: I didn't copy that loop to my home pc, but I had something along the lines like this, but the logic I'm not too sure about either as when I would have to iterate through the second listbox.
For (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (item.Selected)
     {
       newVar = Listbox1.SelectedItem + ListBox2.SelectedItem
      }
}

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of your expected outcome.  Also, edit your question and strip out all except the relevant parts.  That will cut down on clutter and make it easier for people to read.

Comment: Done, added expected output plus trimmed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, based on the desired result you posted, this might be what you want...

```
    ListItem newItem = null;
    foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            foreach (ListItem innerItem in ListBox2.Items)
            {
                if (innerItem.Selected)
                {
                    newItem = new ListItem();
                    newItem.Text = item.Text + innerItem.Text;
                    ListBoxResult.Items.Add(newItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to where you got innerItem from, is that something I would have to declare, or is that a keyword that should be recognized, because right now it tells me that innerItem does not exist in the current context. Sorry if question sounds stupid.

Comment: @ShahinBenom did you copy exactly what Seth typed?  innerItem is being declared in that code.

Comment: oops sorry, I made a typo, about to redo it. Thanks

Comment: I just copied it right, and that was exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you both very much!